# Why do memory leaks occur when executing an event in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, dom, memory, memory-management, memory-leaks

I have in my html a button with an id called "btn".

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
        <title>Index</title>
    </head>

    <body>
        <button id="btn">Click!!!</button>
        <script src="./script.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

The purpose is that each time it is pressed it will show or hide an image,

When `click`, an image is created from a template, its content is extracted and inserted into the DOM after the button and template is set to `null`, when the button is pressed again, it checks if the image It is already in the dom, if it is, it removes it and the reference sets it to `null`, this is the `script.js`:

```
const btn = document.getElementById('btn');

btn.addEventListener('click', () => {
    let img = document.getElementById('img');

    if (!img) {
        let template = document.createElement('template');
        template.innerHTML = '<img id="img" src="./img.jpg" alt="Image"/>';

        btn.after(template.content);
        template = null;
    } else {
        img.remove();
        img = null;
    }
});
```

When the event is triggered, the memory grows more and more, it should not be increasing, it should remain more or less constant, since, are the references removed once the scope of the function ends? Or not?
[image]

After waiting approximately 1 to 2 minutes, the memory recently decreases, but still does not return to the initial value (that is, approximately 16,000 K, although the image is not in memory and not in the DOM):

[image]

what is happening? Should variables be automatically removed from a scope when it ends? or are they not deleted at the exact moment the scope ended? Am I understanding something wrong? Hope you can help me understand :)

Comment: Do you actually observe any problems? Dou you know when garbage collection runs? Run that code a few thousand or million times and only if the code actually crashes / cause ooms are you in trouble. Detecting leaks is not as easy as just looking at memory at two points in time.

Comment: `btn.after(template.content);` inserts the created element to the DOM. You can set a local variable `template` to `null`, but it doesn't remove the element from the DOM.

Comment: Well first, `null` is still an object. Also, javascript isn't the only process that requires memory.

Comment: If the aim is to show and hide an image why not leave it in the DOM and toggle its `hidden` attribute.  That will cost no extra memory

Comment: @mplungjan My purpose is to remove the element from memory, if I don't need it or I don't need to show it, why should I keep it in memory? My idea is to free the memory mainly, for this reason, I want to understand how the memory works when I do this in the listener.

Comment: It is not your job to manage memory. If you really care about it you need to start actual profiling, which is not done by looking at the memory at just two points in time.

Comment: If you don't want to show it now but want to show it later, it makes sense to have it and just change the visibility instead of considering what memory it takes